# Laravel virtual column in model

Tags: php, laravel, virtual

I have one question, how can I create a virtual column ( computed ) in the model?

I searched and just found how to set Attributes, but I need a virtual column, for example, if I will call Post::all() there must be that virtual column called title_body for example:

```
$post->title . ' ' . $post->body
```

and in Post:all(); i must get that column.
How can I do this? is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$appends` like in your `Post` model:

```
/**
 * Appends
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = [
    'title_body',
];

public function getTitleBodyAttribute()
{
    return $this->title . ' ' . $this->body;
}
```